# How to configure routes when using areas in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Scenario:
I have 3 Areas named- **Albums**, **Singers** , **Music**
Now each of these areas have controllers with same name. For instance every area has LoginController.

Now currently I am getting following exception

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Login'
>   This can happen if the route that services this request does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. 
>   If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

This is auto generated Configuration by Visual Studio on Area Creation

```
 public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Albums"
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Albums_Default"
            "Client/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

This is my intial configuration in **RoutesConfig.cs**

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Application_Name" }
        );
```

Now how to configure the routes that without any **modification** in url, the desired view is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one :

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }, // Defaults
        new[]{"AreasDemoWeb.Controllers"}                       // Namespaces
      );
    }
```

[Help Link 1](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx/)

[Help Link2](http://blog.falafel.com/duplicate-controller-names-aspnet-mvc-areas/)